# Backbone.js didn't parse data in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm using backbone.js to build a web site. It runs fine in our development server, but it didn't parse data in client's server using IE7-9. (Firefox, Safari are fine)

I found that backbone call fetch() to request data, but it don't start parse() when data return. I can't find success or error return. There is a part of code:

```
EMR.CategoriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url : 'contents/json/categories.txt',

        initialize:function () {
            console.log('Get data from:', this.url);
            this.fetch();
        },

        model: EMR.ItemModel,

        parse : function(data) {
            console.log("CategoriesCollection parse data:", [data]);
            return data; 
        }
    });
```

Please compare two links below ( in IE 7-9 ), they are same set of code, just server difference:

It works:
1) http://pms.dq.hk/clients/amex_eMR/client/cn/emr/test_data.html

It fail:
2) http://qwww.americanexpress.com/hk/cn/emr/test_data.html

If backbone sent fetch(), but parse() didn't trigger, how to trace the issue?

Any possible ways I can try?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

the only differences between the two that I can see are the response headers..

your server:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Date    Thu, 31 May 2012 03:41:16 GMT
Etag    "ae6691-123ac-59de3b00"
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=98
Server  Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.3.2 DAV/2
```

client server:

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=big-5
Date    Thu, 31 May 2012 03:41:25 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 22 May 2012 06:41:10 GMT
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

the content-type in the client server response caught my eye, but I'm no IE expert.. you might want to mention what version of IE you're having issues with and test some other versions to isolate it..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tested IE 7-9, all of them have problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Any possible ways I can try?

Hello. Did you try to add a error callback to the fetch method? 
Also, the «fail» server send gzipped content in gzipped form. Maybe IE can't handle gzipped JSON in correct way? Or maybe you can try to change the Content-Type header from «text/plain» to «application/json»?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-problem-with-ie8-and-encoding-error-c00ce56e

Our client's server return data in

```
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=big-5
```

When I added a error handler in fetch(), I can see a error return "Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e". It is the reason parse() doesn't work.

I can't change client's server setting, so I put the data file to other directory that returns Content-Type text/plain; to fix the problem.